# IDE for PHP and Python Windows

Tags: php, python, ide

I used to use netbeans for a while and really liked it.

But now, I wan't to expand my toolbox with Python, and Netbeans dropped support for Django, also Python support seems to suck in NB 7.0.

So I am looking for recommendations on IDE or Text Editor for Windows with support:

- Python (possibly with Django)
- PHP
- HTML, CSS, JavaScript
- FTP
- GIT & SVN

I know Aptana 3 can do this, is there anything else?

I don't know Vim a lot, but would that be an option?

Comment: Vim would be an option, but it requires a different workflow, since it's a text editor and not an IDE.

Comment: agree with @tdammers . vim is certainly an option, but it will take months if not weeks to get used to and creating your own custom IDE features in it. (I am using vim as my primary editor for past 2-3 weeks and I am still learning new stuff about vim everyday)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ would be my first choice. JetBrains does a great job with making the editor valuable to you for more than just text entry. The different IDEs JetBrains offers are all basically the same even if they are configured for a slightly different language set.

Eclipse is an option, it has plugins for everything. I've never been much of a fan of Eclipse though. It's really plugable but not a great IDE compared to some of the other options.

Comment: I've downloaded trial versions of both PHPStorm and PyCharm, and truly they have same options for html,js,css etc... One supports PHP, other Python so it's easy to switch and i don't plan to use both on same project either. And i have to say that this IDE looks very nice, i'll stick with it. Eclipse is free, but as someone have mentioned - it's also buggy!. And Netbeans... doesn't support Django. Besides, today i automaticly updated and crash. Ugly behaviour. About vim - ill try to learn it on some regular txt files or quick editing needs, but for projects dev i think it's too light.

Comment: @Luigi, I disagree that Vim is light. It has some very powerful features. Perhaps you should glance at its features. :) It just has a learning curve. I use it over Adobe Dreamweaver for my web development. :)

Comment: :) I'll give it a try for sure, but first as a text editor. Because it looks and acts diffrent from everything else i know.

Comment: Vim does provide a lot of power, for many people I'm not sure they care now that IDEs can provide things like easy refactors, quick keys for navigation (type, member, file, reference, definition), integration with development servers for web stuff. Now I have to admit that Vim + AutoTest can be some nice magic, it's hard to compare.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyEclipse](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/lamp.html)

Comment: Seems like aptana well using lots of aptana components. @Gerry have you noticed any difference?

Comment: @sayth to be honest I don't even remember making this post and that would have been the last time I used EasyEclipse as I don't really develop on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well Aptana is built upon eclipse, so you could just use the basic eclipse with all your necessary add ons.

Obviously you'll need Pydev for the python stuff and that has Django integration.

For some reason though I actually prefer netbeans for my php ide.

Tbh just try out a few and see which one you like best.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and Visual Studio have plugins for just about everything. Eclipse is free, I think for Visual Studio though you'd have to get the professional version to run plugins...

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) - If you are using 64-bit Windows do not hurry to install updates on 7.0+. 6.* is working fine.

You have ftp and you can set to upload on run of the project or on each save. You can download Python plugin by adding this [url](http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz). It is not the best but it worked for me.

It is stable engough and powerful, since the eclipses are very buggy to me.

Aptana is currently the eclipse for web projects, and the people who are creating it are also the creators of pydev, so it would be my second choise.

Visual Studio's plugin VC.Php (Paid) is also powerful, because Visual Studio environment is good, but the plugin is buggy, too and sometimes seems to be updated with dalay of new suff, as whole it would be my 3rd choise.